# Change min. amount allowed in Woocommerce and add more decimals to prices

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm looking to change the minimum amount allowed for woocommerce, as well as adding 3 or more decimals to the products prices. For what I see, Woocommerce starts displaying the prices starting only at 0.01, if the amount is lower than that, then it shows product as FREE, however the price I want to display is something like 0.005, or even something like 0.0025. 
Is it possible to change that default settings from woocommerce?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you looked at the WooCommerce settings? Because "number of decimals" is under "Currency Options" on the first page of "General Options".

Comment: Yes, but what I'm getting with that is only 0's, if for instance I'm setting 4 decimals, I'm getting 0.0500, however I m looking for 0.0555.

Comment: After you've changed the setting, you may need to re-enter the value with 4 decimal places (0.0555) and save the product again. Otherwise, you may have a conflict or something with your theme/other plugins, because I'm seeing the desired behavior with WooCommerce.